# Selectively route traffic to interface

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn, iproute

I have set up a separate routing table (tovpn)

```
#echo 200 tovpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Now I assign routes to it.

Where 10.0.0.1 is the tun2 P-t-P and 10.0.0.2 is the inet

```
#ip route add 10.0.0.1 dev tun2 table tovpn  
#ip route add default via 10.0.0.2 dev tun2 table tovpn
```

Some network 172.20.20.0/24 has traffic forwarded to the table

```
#ip rule add from 172.22.22.0/24 table tovpn  
#iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.22.22.0/24 -o tun2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Great, everything works.

How do I specify traffic additional traffic to pass through the tunnel by specifying the host ip?

The following does not work, if I would like to route, for example, traffic to 8.8.4.4 over the tunnel.

```
#ip rule add to 8.8.4.4/32 table tovpn
```

alternatively

```
#ip rule add to 8.8.4.4/32 lookup tovpn
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi, answers go in the Answer section, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My routing table was incorrectly setup. Correct setup as follows:

```
# ip route add $PTPADDR src $INETADDR proto kernel dev tun1 table tovpn  
# ip route add default dev tun1 table tovpn
```

Now mark packets with

```
# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $LANINTERFACE -d 8.8.8.8/32 -j MARK --set-mark 300
```

Comment: Please be sure to [mark your answer accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you're able.